# disable an input field when command button clicked

Tags: apex, javascript, list, commandbutton, document

I have below piece of code where click on Coach button needs to disable input field Outcome. I have placed that in below code which is not giving desired output. Can someone please let me know?

Apex Page:

```
            <apex:tabPanel rerender="pms">
                <apex:tab label="HCP Detail Calls" >
                    <apex:pageblockTable id="HCPDetail" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" var="itr" >
                     <apex:column headervalue="Coach">
                       <apex:actionRegion >                                    
                                <apex:actionStatus id="SaveStatus_HCP_Detail">
                                    <apex:facet name="start"  >                                            
                                        <apex:outputText value="Saving...!" />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                    <apex:facet name="stop"  >
                                        <apex:image url="/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png" title="Saved Successfully" rendered="{!itr.Id == targetId}" />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                </apex:actionstatus>
                    <apex:inputField id="out" value="{!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c}" onchange="jsCoachSave('{!itr.Id}','{!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c}');" />
                 <!--   <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.out}').disabled = {!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c}; </script> -->
                    <apex:inputField label="Transaction Type" value="{!itr.Recordtype.name}" style="display:none;"/>

                            <apex:commandButton id="chk" value="Coach" onclick="jsCoachSave('{!itr.Id}','{!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c}');" action="{!reset}" rerender="none"/>
                          </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Incident ID ">
                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!itr.Id}">{!itr.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!itr.Account_abv__c}"/>
                        <!--  <apex:column value="{!itr.Call_abv__c}"/>              -->
                        <apex:column value="{!itr.Product_abv__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!itr.Time_of_Event_ABS_abv__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!itr.Audit_Reason_abv__c}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Transaction Type" value="{!itr.Recordtype.name}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome" >
                            <apex:actionRegion >
                                <apex:actionStatus id="SaveStatus">
                                    <apex:facet name="start"  >                                            
                                        <apex:outputText value="Saving...!" />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                    <apex:facet name="stop"  >
                                        <apex:image url="/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png" title="Saved Successfully" rendered="{!itr.Id == targetId}" />
                                    </apex:facet>
                                </apex:actionstatus>
                                <apex:inputField id="chk1" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" onchange="jsCallSave('{!itr.Id}','{!itr.Recordtype.name}');"  rendered="{!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c == false}">
                                </apex:inputField>
                                <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.chk1}').disabled = {!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c}; </script>
                                <apex:inputField label="Transaction Type" value="{!itr.Recordtype.name}" style="display:none;"/>
                            </apex:actionRegion>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" rendered="{!itr.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c == true}"/>
                        </apex:column>


                    </apex:pageblockTable>
                </apex:tab>
            </apex:tabPanel>
```

Please find jsCoachSave function here.

```
function jsCoachSave(citId,Attest){
            document.getElementById('pg:fm:iTargetId').value = citId;
            document.getElementById('pg:fm:iAttest').value = Attest;                
            CoachSave(citId,Attest);  //

        }
```

It calls apex function CoachSave as below.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code when your are clicking on Button
as well **jsCoachSave** javascript method also not present in your code.

```
$('[id$=apexInputFieldId]').attr("disabled","true");
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where to place this exactly? This approach would suffice for me I guess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: onclick of button will be enough if you don't have much functionality depend when clicked on button. else you can keep in a method and call that method from onclick of button.

Comment: Can you please do the page level change here? I am not getting it exactly. Sorry for that. :(

Comment: ok. what this does "jsCoachSave". can i remove this?

Comment: Please find jsCoachSave editted in the question. This is required to do necessary DML in a method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25625/discussion-between-ankuli-and-sfdc-learner).